# Can the Squeeze Theorem be applied in this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am finding if the sequence
$$(-1)^n\frac{(n+1)!}{3n!}$$ is convergent or divergent. I want to clarify that this sequence is divergent since the Squeeze theorem cannot be applied here (because there is (n+1)! in the numerator) and when simplified, the sequence yields to {$(-1)^n\frac{(n+1)}{3}$}; thus, the sequence does not approach to a single value. Am I right?

Comment: Are you sure you have $(3)(n!)$ and not $(3n)!$ in the denominator?

Comment: Yes. The term in the denominator is not enclosed in a parenthesis.

Comment: Correct. The sequence is unbounded, so it cannot have a limit. The series emerging by summing up the entries does not converge either.